# Xamarin Forms - How to get Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment Manager from View Renderer in Android project?

Tags: xamarin.forms, fragmentmanager, adaptive-cards

Xamarin Forms - I have created one adaptive card custom renderer in my android project. In order to call the adaptive card renderer function, I need to pass in Fragment Manager. How can I get fragment manager from View Renderer?

In Xamarin.Android project, I can access fragment manager from fragment class. But Xamarin.Forms I have no idea of how to doing that.

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BaseTemplate.CustomViews.AdaptiveCardLayout), typeof(BaseTemplate.Droid.Renderers.DroidAdaptiveCardLayoutRenderer))]

namespace BaseTemplate.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class DroidAdaptiveCardLayoutRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdaptiveCardLayout, Android.Views.View>, ICardActionHandler
    {
        public DroidAdaptiveCardLayoutRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public void OnAction(BaseActionElement p0, RenderedAdaptiveCard p1)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnMediaPlay(BaseCardElement p0, RenderedAdaptiveCard p1)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnMediaStop(BaseCardElement p0, RenderedAdaptiveCard p1)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdaptiveCardLayout> e)
        {
            CardRendererImplementation cardRenderer = new CardRendererImplementation();
            ICardActionHandler cardActionHandler;
            Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
            cardRenderer.Context = context;

            //how to get fragment manager here?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Context** to cast into activity. As your **DroidAdaptiveCardLayoutRenderer** have the default constructor with the **context** as a parameter.

**Try this Code:**

```cs
var activity = Context as Activity;
activity.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.container, BasicFragment.NewInstance()).Commit();
```

**For V4 use:**

```cs
using Android.Support.V7.App;

activity = Context as AppCompatActivity;
activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Replace(Resource.Id.container, BasicFragment.NewInstance()).Commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, *activity.FragmentManager = Android.App.FragmentManager*

I wish to get *Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager* instead.

Comment: @Lily.T, Please check my updated answer for Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager

Answer (score 1):

That is quite easy actually!

You should be using [CurrentActivity](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin) plugin setup [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin#version-20)

Once you are done with this use the Activity property

```cs
var appcompatActivity= CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity as AppCompatActivity;
var mFragManager= appcompatActivity.SupportFragmentManager;
```